# How to find total size of files in ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)

Tags: vb.net

I have the below code that collects certain files in a directory and places them in a collection of string. I would like to find the total size of all files in that collection. I have tried .Length, however it says that Length is not a member of Collection(Of String). I have also tried working with FileInfo, however, it doesn't seem to work for what I need. Ultimately, I want to display the total size in a messagebox.

```
Dim counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text,
        FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.jpg", "*.wav", "*.pf_import")
```

Here is an example of one attempt, however it gives me the value of 42, when the true value is 16.5MB.

```
Dim fi As String
For Each fi In counter
FileLen += fi.Length
```

I also tried this example, however, it gives me 0.

```
Dim fi As String
Dim filesize As Integer
For Each fi In counter
FileLen += filesize
```

Can someone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: fi is going to end up being the filename, so essentially you are just getting the length of all the filenames here.

Comment: `counter` is going to be a collection of file names - you are apparently adding the length of the names (`As String`).  use `GetFileInfo` to...get file info (or `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`). the last one gives you 0 because `filesize` is never set to anything 0+0=0

Comment: I totally see where I was going wrong! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through each file and call the GetFileInfo function and retrieve the Length property which is the size in bytes:

```
Dim length As Integer = 0
For Each f In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text,
        FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.jpg", "*.wav", "*.pf_import")
length += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(f).Length
Next
```

Then convert from bytes to megabytes:

```
Dim totalKB As Double = length/1024.0 ' To Kilobytes
Dim totalMB As Double = totalKB/1000 ' To Megabytes
```